# Wordpress pagination with get_posts?

Tags: query-posts, pagination, get-posts

I need to make adjustments to a horribly written WP theme that (a custom theme that was written in tables, and bad code).

The theme has several custom templates, but pagination wasn't used and get_posts was used in place of query_posts -

```
    <?php query_posts('showposts=1'); ?>
    <?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&offset=0&category_name=albertsons, carrs, dominicks, genuardis, heb, kroger, pavillions, publix, randalls,safeway,shop-rite,tom-thumb,vons,whole-foods'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
    <?php static $count2 = 0; if ($count2 == "10") { break; } else { ?>

...

    <?php $count2++; } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I need to get pagination to work with get_posts, or rewrite the function to use query_posts only, so that I can add `'paged' => get_query_var('page')`

When I try to rewrite to only use query_posts, the whole damn thing breaks.

Update:

```
<?php 
global $wp_query;

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;


query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => '3','paged'=>$paged,'category_name'=>'albertsons, carrs, dominicks, genuardis, heb, kroger, pavillions, publix, randalls,safeway,shop-rite,tom-thumb,vons,whole-foods')); ?>
                    ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Which shows the loop, but the pagination isn't working. If I click "older posts" the url changes to page-2, but the content is exactly the same.

Comment: I think we'll need whole code from you theme's index.php to help you

Comment: @Mamaduka This snippet is from a custom post template, I don't see how the index.php will be helpful...

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought it was from index.php, than we need code from your theme's custom post template file

Comment: @Mamaduka the code is included, the rest is layout.

Answer (score 1):

This is all sorts of wrong. First don't use `start_wp();` I think that was depreciated 4 years ago. Second your loop is messy, `query_posts` is for altering the main loop, aka not `get_posts`.

So just write it normally using `get_posts` or `WP Query`.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 
               'offset'=> 0, 
               'category_name' => 'carrs, dominicks, genuardis, etc', 
                );


$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

$count_posts = $the_query->current_post + 1; // use this to count your posts

//your loop stuff
endwhile;
```

In not sure how you want your pagination to work, if you just want next/previous links use `<?php previous_post(); ?>    <?php next_post(); ?>` for true numbered pagination I recommend a plugin like WP-PageNavi or WP-Paginate that easily integrated into your theme through a function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links

Comment: see edit. I'm getting the loop, but the pagination isn't working.

Comment: Have a look at this , http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/pagination-resolving-to-first-page-only

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of whether you can use pagination on a get_posts array

Comment: His question was altered and the link above answers his question, thus the comment...