# Pagination Not Working (pages duplicating content)

Tags: php, functions, pagination

My pagination pages echo out the same content on every page.
Page one is queried to show two posts, which it shows up correctly.
Page two shows the exact same two posts as page one does.
Here is my code:
(functions.php) (this is a pre-made code I found on the web).

```
function wp_corenavi() {
  global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
  $pages = '';
  $max = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
  if (!$current = get_query_var('paged')) $current = 1;
  $a['base'] = str_replace(999999999, '%#%', get_pagenum_link(999999999));
  $a['total'] = $max;
  $a['current'] = $current;

  $total = 1; //1 - display the text "Page N of N", 0 - not display
  $a['mid_size'] = 5; //how many links to show on the left and right of the current
  $a['end_size'] = 1; //how many links to show in the beginning and end
  $a['prev_text'] = '&laquo; Previous'; //text of the "Previous page" link
  $a['next_text'] = 'Next &raquo;'; //text of the "Next page" link

  if ($max > 1) echo '<div class="navigation">';
  if ($total == 1 && $max > 1) $pages = '<span class="pages">Page ' . $current . ' of ' . $max . '</span>'."\r\n";
  echo $pages . paginate_links($a);
  if ($max > 1) echo '</div>';
}
```

(Custom Page Template)

```
<?php

get_header(); 

if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content" role="main">

                <?php query_posts( 'category_name=category&showposts=2'); ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="thumb">
                                      <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?> 
                                   </div>
                                    <h2 class="entry-title" style="text-align:center;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                    <div class="the-excerpt">
                                        <?php echo content(15, __('(Read More)')); /* twentyten_posted_on(); */ ?>
                                    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
                                </div>
                            </div>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
                <br clear="all" />
                <?php if (function_exists('wp_corenavi')) wp_corenavi(); ?>
            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #container -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) resets the query. See this warning on the Codex page:

> Pagination won't work correctly, unless you use query_posts() in a
>   page template and you set the 'paged' query var appropriately:
>   http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html

The call:

```
query_posts( 'category_name=category&showposts=2');
```

does not tell it which page to get (so it gets the first page). It's a simple matter of:

```
$page = get_query_var('paged');
$page = (!empty($page) ? $page : 1);
query_posts( 'category_name=category&showposts=2&paged='.$page);
```

**Note:** For pages (i.e. when using a custom page template, you need to use `get_query_var('page')` rather than `get_query_var('paged')`.

Comment: I'm getting the error: Can't use function return value in write context in....
`get_header(); 
$page = (!empty(get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1);
query_posts( 'category_name=category&showposts=2&paged='.$page);
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>`

Comment: Corrected answer. Also see Chip's comments about `if ( have_posts() ) :` and using `WP_Query`, rather than `query_posts`. :D

Comment: Not sure I understand Stephen?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what happened. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, you're modifying your query *inside* of your Loop, which begins with your `if ( have_posts() ) :` conditional. Move this *outside* the query:

```
 <?php query_posts( 'category_name=category&showposts=2'); ?>
```

Second, you don't want to use [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) for anything other than [*modifying the Primary Loop*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Alters_Main_Loop). As this is a custom Page template, the Primary Loop is the *Page content*. Your category query is a *secondary* loop. So, **you should be using [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of `query_posts()` for this secondary loop**.

Third, whenever you create a secondary loop that requires pagination, you need to tell WordPress to paginate based on the *secondary loop's query, instead of paginating based on the Primary Loop's query*.  That question [has been dealt with extensively](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom%20loop%20pagination) here on WPSE; [here's one example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop).

To modify it for your use case, do something like this:

```
<?php
// Custom query args
$category_query_args = array(
    'category_name' => 'category'
    'posts_per_page' => 2
);
// Custom query
$category_query = new WP_Query( $category_query_args );

// Reset pagination
global $wp_query;
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = $category_query;

// Output the Loop
if ( $category_query->have_posts() ) : 
?>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content" role="main">

while ( $category_query->have_posts() ) : $category_query->the_post();
?>
<div>
     <div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?> 
        </div>
        <h2 class="entry-title" style="text-align:center;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="the-excerpt">
             <?php echo content(15, __('(Read More)')); /* twentyten_posted_on(); */ ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </div>
</div>
<?php
endwhile;

// Custom navigation
?>
<br clear="all" />
<?php if (function_exists('wp_corenavi')) wp_corenavi(); ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->

<?php
endif;

// Reset query
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

#### Edit

p.s. you should be using `posts_per_page` rather than `showposts`, which is deprecated.

#### Edit 2

By the way, WordPress already provides a function for paginating links: [**`paginate_links()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links). It is pretty straightforward to use, though it does require more arguments than the typical WordPress function. [Here's how I use it in Oenology](https://github.com/chipbennett/oenology/blob/master/functions/custom.php#L1026).

Comment: I'm getting the same issue after I duplicated this. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/eRbJPAqy

Comment: And what happens if you use core navigation functions, rather than the custom navigation function?

Comment: Using the wordpress default nav I'm getting the same issue, http://pastebin.com/UfCzLTfY

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I found: [Pagination resolving to first page only](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/pagination-resolving-to-first-page-only#answer-2641)

```
global $query_string;
parse_str( $query_string, $my_query_array );
$paged = ( isset( $my_query_array['paged'] ) && !empty( $my_query_array['paged'] ) ) ? $my_query_array['paged'] : 1;
query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=3&paged='.$paged);
```